# How do you use Linq to connect tables in different databases?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, view, or-designer

I'm a bit of a Linq newbie, and I couldn't find any documentation to help me with what seems to be a pretty trivial problem - so your help will be much appreciated!

I have a table `Table1` in database `DB1`, which has a "pseudo" foreign key `Table2ID` to table `Table2` in database `DB2`, on the same server.  "Pseudo", because obviously I can't have an *actual* FK spanning two databases.

Now I'm playing around with the O/R designer, and I love the way all the relationships are generated when I bring database objects into the designer... very cool!  And I want my `Table1` object to have a relationship to `Table2`, just like it has relationships with all the "real" foreign key-related objects in `DB1`.  But I can't bring `Table2` into my db diagram, because it's in the wrong DB.

To synthesize this, I tried creating a view `Table2` in `DB1`, which is simply `select * from DB2..Table2`.  Aha, now I can drop a `Table2` object into my diagram.  I can even make a parent/child relationship between `Table1` and `Table2`.  But when I look at the generated code, `Table1` still has no relationship to `Table2`, which I find most perplexing.

Am I missing a step somewhere?  Is there a better/recommended way of doing this?

Thanks!

---

### Later...

Along the lines of what one person suggested, I tried filling in the partial class of `Table1` with all the methods required to access `Table2`, by copying all the structures for a related object within the same DB.

This actually worked for reads, but as soon as I tried to update or insert a record, I got an exception:

`An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.`

So it looks like the designers of Linq have actually thought about this scenario, and decided that you are **not allowed** to connect objects in different databases.  That's really a shame... :(

---

### ... and even later...

Thanks to @williammandra.com, I found that you need to create the primary key on a view manually.  But there's still another problem: for some reason when you load a value from the view `Table2` and set it on the new record `Table1`, then commit changes, it tries to insert a **new** record into `Table2`, which obviously causes a PK violation.  Any idea why this happens, and how to get around it?

Comment: Follow up to this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795196/linq-problem-with-inserting-new-rows-that-have-references-to-existing-records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views don't have primary keys (without it the O/R designer can't create the relationship). Your solution to use a view gets you halfway there.... The step you are missing is setting the "Primary Key" property to true in the O/R designer for the key field in the Table2 view. You still have to create the association manually, but once you save the dbml the relationship will show up in the generated code.

Comment: Thank you - I was in the middle of discovering this myself at the same time as you were writing it!

Comment: Only problem is, for some reason it doesn't accept when you set the "foreign key" to a loaded value from the view; it tries to insert a new record, and you get a primary key violation error.  Dod you happen to know what the "secret switch" is to get past this problem?

Comment: Aha, I came across the same problem in a related table.  So it's not just about views.  Credit (and bounty!) for the correct answer to this question therefore goes to you here; I'll post the next problem as a separate question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could create two dbml's, one for each db. Then join the tables in your query:

```
var tb1 = DataContext1.Table1
var tb2 = DataContext2.Table2

var result = (from t1 in tb1
              join t2 in tb2 on tb1.column equals tb2.column
              where ...
              select ...
             )
```

You could also set tb2 = to your view rather than another datacontext...

Comment: That would work, but it's not exactly the effect I'm gunning for.  If you have two tables in the same DB, then the O/R Designer creates a relationship between the two, e.g. Table1.Table2 - I want the same interface in my data context, just with Table2 in a different DB.

Comment: You should be able to right-click on the view in the dbml designer and go to add -> association to create a relationship between the view and the table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can access one database from the other you can do this by manually editing the .dbml file.

```
<Table Name="Table1.dbo.Table" Member="MemberObject"> 
<Table Name="Table2.dbo.Table" Member="MemberObject">
```

You might actually be able do this by looking at the properties of a table and changing the source.

Comment: The problem with this is that if he needs to regenerate the dbml his changes will be lost