# Linq problem with inserting new rows that have references to existing records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

(I believe this is the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785291/why-is-linq-to-sql-entity-association-creating-a-new-duplicate-row-when-inserti), but there's no answer there, and I think I can express the problem better here...)

I have two Linq-to-SQL classes, `State` and `County`, where `County` has a FK to `State`.  Here's some test code:

```
State s = State.GetState("NY"); // here I do a load of a State class via the Linq DataContext
County c = new County();
c.Name = "Rockland";
c.State = s;
MyDataContext.GetTable<County>().InsertOnSubmit(c);
MyDataContext.SubmitChanges(); // throws an exception
```

The exception thrown is `"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_State'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.State'"`.

In other words, what appears to be happening here is that despite my having loaded `s` as an existing record, when I attempt to insert `c`, Linq is assuming that all related objects, `State` included, also need to be inserted!

This is completely absurd, and I cannot believe that Microsoft would have made such a huge blunder - so it must be that somewhere my own understanding is faulty.

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong, and what the correct approach here is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `State.GetState(...)` function using the same datacontext as `MyDataContext.GetTable<County>()`?

Comment: Not quite the full solution - see my answer below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795196/linq-problem-with-inserting-new-rows-that-have-references-to-existing-records/795430#795430

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't right here. I'm assuming State -> Count is a one to many relationship. In which case, the correct way of doing this is:

```
State s = State.GetState("NY"); // here I do a load of a State class via the Linq DataContext
County c = new County();
c.Name = "Rockland";

s.Counties.Add(c);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Since State is the parent table, you need to add the counties to the state's counties collection.

Comment: OK, that's all well for counties; it may make sense for State to have a Counties collection.  But let's say we've got a Person object, with an address including a State.  Are you going to give your State a People collection?  I don't want to pollute my State object's interface with collections of every Tom, Dick and Harry table that decides they want a FK to State...

Answer (score 0):

### Solved!

[John Boker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795196/linq-problem-with-inserting-new-rows-that-have-references-to-existing-records/795319#795319) asked:

> is the State.GetState(...) function
>   using the same datacontext as
>   MyDataContext.GetTable() ?

My answer was "Yes" - they are using the same DataContext class... but they were using different **instances**.

**Lesson learned:** always use the same **instance** of your DataContext class for any objects you're planning to persist to your DB!

(John gets credit for the answer, anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

If the State didn't use the same DataContext instance it might work to call the Attach method first.